# How to disable link rel="preload" on responsive?

Tags: html, responsive, pagespeed-insights

I work with Link rel="preload" for slideshow images to make my website faster, at least in a browser. I created a rule for not showing the slideshow on a phone ( display:none; ). As the preload links are in the head of my index.html, images are preloaded even on a phone. Is there a way to disable this preload when we are on responsive?

I created a rule for not showing the slideshow on a phone ( display:none; ).

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media attribution to preload:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="small_cat.jpg" as="image" media="(max-width: 400px)">
```

This is [well supported in browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_link_media).